# PHPExcel set decimal separator for CSV

Tags: excel, csv, phpexcel, export-to-csv, decimal-point

I use PHPExcel to create XLSX files. I also want to alternatively export my files as CSV which can be opened in Excel. In countries such as Gernamy, France, or Spain Excel expects a comma as decimal separator for numbers (e.g. "3,14"). But PHPExcel by default uses a dot (e.g. "3.14"). This leads Excel to either interpret the number as text or as a date (e.g. March 2014 for 3.14) but not as a number.

So how can I change the decimal point for the PHPExcel CSV export?

Comment: PHPExcel outputs numbers in the same way that PHP outputs numbers by default, with a decimal point.... if you need to change that behaviour, then you'll need to modify the CSV Writer to apply those changes (e.g applying number_format() to float values), because there's nothing built-in to do it for you

Comment: OK thanks, I will modify the CSV Writer. This would be a nice feature for the future because commas as decimal separators are quite common around the world: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DecimalSeparator.svg (bright green is comma, blue is point)

Comment: They are common, but this is the first time I've ever heard of MS Excel's CSV importer misinterpreting a file because of a decimal point rather than a comma..... in over 12 years of PHPExcel, nobody has ever requested this before

Comment: I'll take a look at how to easily enable the functionality in the Writer.... and if it's really that commonplace, then the CSV Reader will need to be interpret a decimal comma correctly as well

Comment: Thanks! You can test it in Excel if you switch the decimal separator setting (in Windows / Excel 2010: options / advanced / editing options / decimal saparator).